# Input focus not following window clicks

Tags: rhel, gnome, multi-monitor, compiz, ati

I'm running RHEL 6.5 with a generic ATI HD5480 videocard and three monitors (one connected to each port... DVI, DisplayPort, and VGA), and I'm having issues with window-activation and input-focus that are driving me nuts.

Once in a while, I'll click on an inactive window that doesn't currently have input focus (say, a terminal window on a different monitor). The clicked-in window's titlebar color will change, and the window will move to the foreground if anything is obscuring it, but at seemingly-random intervals (usually 3-5 times per day), the newly-activated and raised window won't actually get keyboard input focus unless I click on it a second time.

Aside from being annoying, this has caused me endless headaches when focus remained somewhere in IntelliJ... it has a lot going on, and it isn't necessarily *easy* to figure out which pane the stray input landed in.

According to CompizConfig Settings Manager, I have the following "Focus & Raise Behavior" settings:

```
Click to focus: checked.
Raise on click: checked.
auto-raise: checked.
auto-raise delay: 1000
focus prevention level: off
focus prevention windows: any
```

Any ideas?